# Detect when requestAlwaysAuthorization not called iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am trying to request user's location using multi step process; However, when calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization` if it is not executed I would like to move to show a message.

let me explain better by showing my flow

Here is my current flow

1. Request `While in use`

   - The user chooses `Allow Once` -> Go to `2`
   - the user chooses `Allow While Using App` -> Go to `2`
   - the user chooses `Don't Allow` -> show error message
2. Request `Always permission`

   - The user chooses `Keep Only While Using` -> Show error message (issue #1: I can't detect this)
   - The user chooses `Change to Always Allow` -> Show success message

If from `1` the user chose `Allow Once` I can't even call `requestAlwaysAuthorization` because calling it would result in nothing and even Apple states

> If the user responded to requestWhenInUseAuthorization() with Allow Once, then Core Location ignores further calls to requestAlwaysAuthorization() due to the temporary authorization.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization)

My goal is if users selects `Allow Once` from `1` then `requestAlwaysAuthorization` should be skipped all together.

if from `1` `Allow Wile Using App` is selected and from `requestAlwaysAuthorization` `Keep Only while using` is chosen then I would like to know that state.

I know it can be done, I just don't know how. Here is an app that does what I am trying to achieve

[image] [image] [image]

From the first image user chose `Allow While Using App` then `Keep Only While Using` and they are able to detect it or able to detect the fact that the dialogue appeared and they didn't move to the third image until the user responded.

Another scenario as follows:

[image] [image] [image]

From the first image the user chose `Allow Once` and from the 2nd image no matter what the user choose they will go to image 3 without displaying the always permission (keep in mind the 2nd image is not a real permission, its just buttons that made to trick the user); so they are able to tell the dialogue didn't appear or that the user chose `Allow Once` from the previous step (one or the other and I can't do either one).

Obviously I cant record every combination and post as a gif, so if you would like to experiement the app name is `Zenly`

**So the end goal is to be able to wait for the user to respond to the dialogue if it appears otherwise just move to the next screen.**

Here is what I have done, quoting from apple

> Core Location leaves the authorization as When In Use. The delegate doesn’t receive any updates.

I thought maybe when requesting always I should also execute the delegate manually so to the function `requestAlwaysLocation()` I added the line

```
self.locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(self.locationManager)
```

However, that obviously doesn't work because in the case that `Allow While Using App` was chosen from step `1` and `Change to Always Allow` is chosen from step `2` now the delegate will be called twice...

Then I thought if I can detect the provisioning `When in Use` from step `1` I might be able to bypass but I don't know how to do it.

Here is a snippet of `LocationManager`

```
    func requestWhenInUserLocation()  {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func requestAlwaysLocation() {
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }


    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        print("authroizatino changed")
//        let accuracyAuthorization = manager.accuracyAuthorization
        let status = manager.authorizationStatus

        // -change function will just change some internal properties and will post a notification so views that subscribe to it can react accordingly.
        
        switch status {
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways:
                self.change(permission: .Location, to: .Location(.Always))
                break
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse:
                self.change(permission: .Location, to: .Location(.WhenInUse))
                break
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.denied:
                self.change(permission: .Location, to: .Denied)
                break
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
                self.change(permission: .Location, to: .NotDetermined)
                break
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.restricted:
                self.change(permission: .Location, to: .Location(.Restricted))
                break
            @unknown default:
                self.change(permission: .Location, to: .Unknown)
                break
        }
    }
```

I hope I was able to explain what I want clearly

Comment: This looks like a use case where you should not try and work around the process Apple has put in place. Simply ask for "always" and then enable background location updates. At an appropriate time ios will prompt the user to upgrade your location access.

Comment: How is it a workaround? Apple does allow you to prompt `always` permission at any point you like. I think you refer to the fact that I am trying to detect `Allow Once` or permission is left unchanged when `always` is requested. Unfortunately, there are valid cases for such requirement; for example an app like `Zenly` can't function without it so they require it as part of onboarding. The app I am building is in a similar situation. I would love to not implement this as I can see why it could be considered a `workaround` but It is not my app, this is a client's app.

Comment: Also note that with iOS 14 you don't have to wait for iOS to choose when to upgrade the notification. You have the freewill when to request it if you break it down into 2 steps like I did.

Comment: I understand the process. The changed behaviour was introduced in iOS 13.4 and I have an app in the store that does what you are attempting as it really does need always permission or it just doesn't work. However, if you have told the user why you need always, prompted them for always and you don't have it then you kind of have to live with that. You can check again next time the app launches. You can also check after a `didBecomeActive` event since that means the dialog has been dismissed

Comment: I have tried explaining that to them but they insist on blocking the user from accessing the app during onboarding if `always` is not given. With that being said, the last sentence you wrote is a `golden key`. Thank you so much, I don't know how I never thought of doing so. The saying `hiding in plain sight` definitely applies here. Again thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Paulw11 I was able to solve it. It was rather easy actually.

I cant add any implementation here as it will really depend on one's use case, and I am using SwiftUI.

So what I did was upon pressing the `Request Always` button I would create a `bool` state and set it to true, I also have an observer to the app's active state **THIS IS THE KEY TO SOLVING THIS** and I also have an observer on the `bool` state.

If the bool state changes and the app's active state did not change then the user have chosen `Allow Once`; However, if the state did change then I would wait for it to be active again.

If it becomes active I would check the location permission if it's still `When in Use` then the user chose `Keep Only While Using` otherwise they chose `Change to Always`

All credits go to Paulw11

**EDIT: I also have observer for the app coming to foreground from background in case the user changes the location permission from settings**

**Note:** the above algorithm can be improved quite a lot if you are using `Combine` with SwiftUI. Most of what I wrote is useless, you can just subscribe to the permission and the app's active state.