# Setting location tracking to Always in iOS

Tags: ios, location

In short, I'm working on an app that needs Always On for location tracking. There's no issue making it clear to the user why this is needed.

I'm encountering a similar situation to what is discussed here: [Detect when requestAlwaysAuthorization not called iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761582/detect-when-requestalwaysauthorization-not-called-ios-14).

In the proposed answer, there is a statement: If the bool state changes and the app's active state did not change then the user have chosen `Allow Once`; However, if the state did change then I would wait for it to be active again

However, from what I see, the app will become active if you choose `Allow Once` or `Allow While Using App` - so this does not help to differentiate between the two.

Has anyone solved this issue? Basically, in short I need the app to force the user to choose `Always On` for location information if they want to use the app

Comment: After iOS 13.4 you can ask for "when in use" and then, once you have that permission, ask for "always" to trigger the prompt to upgrade to always. After the prompt for "always" is dismissed then the authorisation will tell you whether you have always or when in use or denied

Comment: Hi Paul, this is the approach I've been testing out. However, any thoughts on differentiating between `Allow Once` and `Allow While Using App` on the first selection screen? If the user select `Allow Once` then the `RequestAlwaysAuthorization` doesn't fire. The CLLocationManager.Status is `authorizedWhenInUse` so programmatically I can't see a difference between the two

Comment: Ultimately you have to do the best you can with the permission you have. If you don't get a didBecomeInactive/willBecomeactive when you request always you know that no permission dialog was shown

Answer (score 0):

Using `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` is all you can do (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization). There is no way to force the user to choose this setting. Users may also always revoke this permission later on, so your app needs to respond to it appropriately. If your app simply doesn't work without it, show an error screen and ask the user to set the permission back to `always`.

Comment: Yes, I would like to show an error screen if the permission is not set to `Always`. However, my current issue lies in the first step when the user can select `Allow Once` or `Allow While Using App`. There is no way to differentiate which option was selected programmatically as far as I've seen

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. From what I understand your app needs always access to the user's location. Check the authorization status after the request and see if it's set to `always` or not